# iOS Simulator how to automate user actions and then continue to debug

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

During the testing I need to do the same operation:

1. Login
2. Navigate to Home Screen
3. Navigate to tab number 1
4. Insert a text to some textfield and press a button

How can I automate this action without doing it manually? So when I hit some screen I would like to continue Debugging from this point by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the view controller you want to debug as a root view controller for the time of testing, and if you need some variables to have data then you can add some dummy data until your debugging is done.

Comment: yea but it's requires sometime more time then just navigate to VC as sometimes we have diff selected option